# reveal.js removing <script> tags

Tags: javascript, reveal.js

I am making a presentation with Reveal.js on slid.es and I am trying to run a script but it doesn't work and i get a messege saying. "Removed 'script' tag found in deck."
Is this because I am wrong in thinking that javascript works in reveal or is it that I am coding badly. (I just started with javascript yesterday). 
Here is some example code

```
<html>
    <body>

    <script>
    cars=["BMW","Volvo","Saab","Ford"];
    for (var i=0;i<cars.length;i++)
    {
    document.write(cars[i] + "<br>");
    }
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Script tags are not currently allowed in presentations on slid.es due to security risks. We may enable this later but it'll take a bit some changes to the architecture.

Comment: Any update on that? It would be a very name feature. Is the best work around to use iframes?